# How to save a text in an alertbox in a list?

Tags: javascript, html, list, alert

In my website i integrated Google Earth. Now when i click at any location i get the coordinates in an alert box. Now i want to save theese coordinates from each point and export these. Does anybody know how to do this? I think i have to save them in a list but i dont know how and how to go on. This is the code i use to create the alertbox:

```
function eventHandler(event) {
var text = 'Click:';

              function addToMessage(append1, append2) { 
                text += ' ' + append1 + ': ' + append2 + '\n' ;
              }

              addToMessage('latitude', event.getLatitude());
              addToMessage('longitude', event.getLongitude());
              addToMessage('altitude', event.getAltitude());

              setTimeout(function() {
                alert(text);
              }, 0);
            }

            google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'click',   eventHandler);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: one way is using "Hidden variable" assign those text value to hidden variables and export them !!

Answer (score 0):

actually i don't understand what is your requirement.. If you want that text as list make an array as global variable and push that text into the array